# ActionScript platformer hitTest

Tags: actionscript, physics, hittest, scroller

I am making a 2D side scroller in actionscript and this is my first ever project using actionscript so I need a little help. I need to be able to test if there is a collision and where it is. For example if the player hit an object on the right side of the bounding box it would stop going right and if the player jumped on top of the object it would stop falling but still be able to go right because there is no collision to the right of the player.

Here is the coding that I have so far for the player. The other object it interacts with is called "plat"
http://pastebin.com/0P30nEd2

Answer (score 0):

hey you really should paste code on this page as it helps others in the future if they need to read this post. you can use hitTest for this task:

```
         example:  myMovieClip1.hitTestObject(myMovieclip2);
```

you can use also hitTestPoint aswell:
Good working tutorials can be found here:
http://sierakowski.eu/list-of-tips/39-collision-detection-methods-hittest-and-hittestobject-alternatives.html